# I want to make a selector in ListView with only java code

Tags: listview, arraylist, adapter, selector, listviewitem

I want to do selector in java. The screen view consists of a listview. I want you to change the gun image when the user presses on a gun for a very short period of time, and effect the selector. But I can not check the ListView item. I threw the changing pictures into the `ArrayList`. How do I do this?

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;**strong text**
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MakinalilarFragment extends Fragment {
    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
    private AudioManager mAudioManager;

    private AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener mOnAudioFocusChangeListener = new AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
            if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT ||
                    focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK) {        
                mMediaPlayer.pause();
                mMediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
            } else if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN) {
                mMediaPlayer.start();
            } else if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS) {

                releaseMediaPlayer();
            }
        }
    };


    private MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener mCompletionListener = new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            releaseMediaPlayer();
        }
    };

    public MakinalilarFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.word_list, container, false);

        mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

        final ArrayList<Gun> guns = new ArrayList<Gun>();
        guns.add(new Gun(R.string.name_aa_12,R.drawable.aa12_medium, R.raw.aa12_sound,R.drawable.fire_aa12));
        guns.add(new Gun(R.string.name_acr,R.drawable.acr_medium, R.raw.acr_sound,R.drawable.fire_acr));
        guns.add(new Gun(R.string.name_ak_47,R.drawable.ak47_medium, R.raw.ak47_sound,R.drawable.fire_ak47));
        guns.add(new Gun(R.string.name_fal,R.drawable.fal_medium, R.raw.fal_sound,R.drawable.fire_fal));
        guns.add(new Gun(R.string.name_intervention,R.drawable.intervention_medium, R.raw.intervention_sound,R.drawable.fire_intervention));
        guns.add(new Gun(R.string.name_m1,R.drawable.m1_medium, R.raw.m1_sound,R.drawable.fire_m1));
        guns.add(new Gun(R.string.name_m4,R.drawable.m4_medium, R.raw.m4_sound,R.drawable.fire_m4));

        GunAdapter adapter = new GunAdapter(getActivity(), guns);
        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                Gun gun = guns.get(position);

                int result = mAudioManager.requestAudioFocus(mOnAudioFocusChangeListener,
                        AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT);

                if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {

                    mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), gun.getAudioResourceId());
                    mMediaPlayer.start();

                    Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                    v.vibrate(500);
                    mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(mCompletionListener);
                }
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        releaseMediaPlayer();
    }

    private void releaseMediaPlayer() {
        if (mMediaPlayer != null) {

            mMediaPlayer.release();
            mMediaPlayer = null;
            mAudioManager.abandonAudioFocus(mOnAudioFocusChangeListener);
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is adapter code**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GunAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Gun> {

    public GunAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Gun> guns) {
        super(context, 0, guns);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View listItemView = convertView;
        if (listItemView == null) {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }


        Gun currentGun = getItem(position);

        TextView nameGunTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);

        nameGunTextView.setText(currentGun.getNameGunId());

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.image);

        imageView.setImageResource(currentGun.getImageResourceId());

        return listItemView;
    }
}
```